# How to find an angle of a non-right angle triangle when given two sides and an area?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

How would I go about finding an angles of a non-right angled triangle when given the area and two of its sides.

For example:

In the triangle $ABC$, $a = 5$, $b = 6$ and the area is $11~\text{cm}^2$. Find the size of Angle $C$.

Thanks for all of your help! :-)

Note:

What is wrong with the current method I am using? (method below)

\begin{align*}
Area & = \frac{ab\sin C}{2}\\
\Rightarrow 2Area & = ab\sin C\\
\Rightarrow \frac{2Area}{ab} & = \sin C\\
\sin C & = \frac{11^2 \cdot 2}{5 \cdot 6}\\
\Rightarrow \sin C & = 8.06
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you familiar with the area formula $A = \frac{1}{2}ab\sin\gamma$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes.

Comment: The area is $11$, not $11^2$, so $\sin C=2\cdot11/(5\cdot6)=22/30=11/15$.

Comment: @BarryCipra You do not know how stupid I feel aha. Such a simple mistake, thanks you ever so much!

Comment: @Dinar, see my profile for a book you might find of interest. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You still need to do this ~ C=sin-1(11/15) 
Because you are trying to find C alone. 
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually, the *solutions* for $C$ are $C=\arcsin\frac{11}{15}$ and $C=\pi-\arcsin\frac{11}{15}$, but I guess in $5$ months the OP has already realized the obvious fact you're pointing out.